# How does String.split work?

Tags: java, regex, split

Why does the following code return the output below?
I would expect that 2 and 3 provide the same string splitting of 1.

```
    Log.d(TAG, " 1 ---------------------------");
String originalText = "hello. .hello1";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+|\\s|\\W|\\d");
Matcher m = p.matcher(originalText);

 while (m.find()) { 
     Log.d(TAG, m.group(0)); 
 }
 Log.d(TAG, "2 --------------------------- " + originalText);

String [] scrollString = p.split(originalText);

int i;      
for (i=0; i<scrollString.length; i++)
    Log.d(TAG, scrollString[i]);

Log.d(TAG, "3 --------------------------- " + originalText);

scrollString = originalText.split("[a-zA-Z]+|\\s|\\W|\\d");


for (i=0; i<scrollString.length; i++)
    Log.d(TAG, scrollString[i]);
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 ---------------------------

hello

.

.

hello

1

2 ---------------------------

3 ---------------------------
```

Comment: Are you sure you used this code to get the result? The `2 --` and `3 --` lines should show the string `hello...` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 1 will find the pattern and return that, whereas No. 2 and 3 will return the text in between the found pattern (which serves as the delimiter in those cases).

Answer (score 1):

Your subject doesn't match what you are asking.

The Subject asks about `String.split()` you are doing `Pattern.split()` which one do you really want help with?

When using `String.split();` you pass in the regular expression to apply to the string, not the string you want to split!

JavaDoc for [String.split();](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
final String s = "this is the string I want to split";
final String[] sa = s.split(" ");
```

you are calling `.split` on `p` ( [Pattern.split();](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) )

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+|\\s|\\W|\\d");
String [] scrollString = p.split(originalText);
```

these too methods have different behaviors.

Comment: p is a Pattern which has a [`split(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence)) method that takes the string to be split

Comment: No problems with calling pattern.split(sourceString) See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Answer (score 0):

the `split()` methods don't add the captured part of the string (the delimiter) to the result array

if you want the delimiters you'll have to play with lookahead and lookbehind (or use version 1)

Answer (score 0):

No. Every character in your string is covered by the split pattern, hence taken as something you *don't* want. Therefore, you get the empty result.

You can imagine that your pattern first finds "hello", then split hopes to find something, but alas!, it  finds another "separation" character.